# Why is my string variable not printing a full string?

Tags: c++

**Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    str[0] = 'a';
    str[1] = 'b';
    str[2] = 'c';

    cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

*No output.*

---

If I replace `cout << str;` with `cout << str[1]`, I get a proper output.

**Output:**

> b

And if I change the data type of the variable to a character array, I get the desired output. (Replacing `string str;` with `char str[5];`

**Output:**

> abc

Why is my program behaving like this? How do I alter my code to get the desired output without changing the data type?

Comment: str has no size but you try to set str[0] .. which do not increase the size of the string and cause Undefined Behavior

Comment: Instead of `str[0] = 'a';` you should use `str += 'a';`

Comment: @drescherjm, yeah... That makes sense.

Comment: lehofah718@cityroyal.org

Comment: use `.at()` to see what's wrong https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/N_T8pJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

```
string str;
```

creates an empty string. It has length `0`.

You are trying to write to the first three elements of this string with

```
str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'c';
```

These do not exist. Indexing a `std::string` out-of-bounds causes undefined behavior.

You can add characters to a string with any of the following methods:

```
str += 'a';
str += "a";
str.push_back('a');
str.append("a");
```

or you can resize the string first to the intended length before you index into any of its elements:

```
str.resize(3);
```

---

As pointed out by @Ayxan in a comment under this answer, you are also missing `#include<string>`. Without it it is *unspecified* whether your program will compile since it uses `std::string` which is defined in `<string>`. It is *unspecified* whether including one standard library header will include another one if there isn't a specific exception. You should not rely on unspecified behavior that may break at any point.

Comment: Also note that OP must include `<string>`

Comment: @Ayxan, that isn't required. He isn't using anything from that library file.

Comment: @Sujit he's using `std::string` class.

Comment: @Ayxan, all he's using is the data type. It will not return any kind of errors. Data types do not require any header files.

Comment: @Sujit see for yourself if it compiles https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nxmiy6

Comment: @Ayxan, I tested it on my compiler running the latest version of C++, works perfectly. Try compiling without `std::`?

Comment: @Sujit no confirming C++ compiler will ever compile this code: `int main() { std::string str; }` (note that no headers are included). You seem to have a misunderstanding about how C++ works fundamentally.

Comment: @Sujit it's `iostream` not `iostream.h`, and it's not guaranteed to compile without the `<string>` header.

Comment: @Ayxan, First off... officially it is a header file with extension `.h`. In later versions we don't use `.h` but the library still has it, so it isn't wrong saying it. Secondly the only reason it's giving that error is because the variable is not used. Compile this: ```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "Hello World!;
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}```

Comment: @Sujit `<iostream.h>` was never part of standard C++. Only some pre-standard compilers used it and these are 20+ years old now. Nobody should use them anymore. It is *unspecified* whether a C++ implementation will include `<string>` when `<iostream>` is included. `<string>` is required because it contains the definition of `std::string`. It is unwise to rely on unspecified behavior when you can make it perfectly specified easily with an additional `#include<string>`. Whether or not `using namespace std;` is present or whether the `std::` prefix is used doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sujit -- *Compile this:* -- ok, [let's compile it](https://rextester.com/PIUJW85635).  You lost.  Also `std::string` is not a fundamental data type.  It is a template class based on `std::basic_char`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [walnut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026759/2445184), here's what's going on under the hood:

An `std::string` contains at least two members, a data pointer (type `char*`) and a size. The `[]` operator does not check the size, it only indexes into the memory behind the data pointer. Also, the `[]` operator does not modify the size member of the string.

The `<<` operator that streams the string to `cout`, however, does interpret the size member. It does so to be able to output strings containing null characters. Since the size member is still zero, nothing is printed.

---

You may wonder why the memory access within `str[0]` even succeeds, after all, the string never had any reason to allocate any memory for its data yet. This is due to the fact that virtually all `std::string` implementations use the small-string-optimization: The `std::string` object itself is a bit larger than it needs to be, and the space at its end is used instead of an allocation on the heap unless the string becomes longer than that space. As such, the default constructor will just point the data pointer to that internal storage to have it initialized, and your memory accesses are directed to existing memory. This is why you don't get a SEGFAULT unless you access the string's data way out of bounds. Doesn't change the fact that already your expression `str[0]` is undefined behavior, though. The symptoms may appear benign, but the disease is fatal.